# Ternary operator (?:) in Bash

Tags: bash, syntax, conditional-operator

Is there a way to do something like this

```
int a = (b == 5) ? c : d;
```

using Bash?

Comment: [@dutCh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955920/52074) shows that `bash` does have something similar to the "ternary operator" however in `bash` this is called the "conditional operator" `expr?expr:expr` (see `man bash` goto section "Arithmetic Evaluation"). Keep in mind the `bash` "conditional operator" is tricky and has some gotchas.

Comment: Bash does have a ternary operator for integers and it works inside the arithmetic expression `((...))`.  See [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic).

Comment: Just as @codeforester mentioned, ternary operator works with arithmetic expansion `$(( ))` and arithmethic evaluation `(( ))`. See also `https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression`.

Answer (score 774, accepted):

ternary operator `? :` is just a short form of `if/then/else`

```
case "$b" in
 5) a=$c ;;
 *) a=$d ;;
esac
```

Or

```
 [[ $b = 5 ]] && a="$c" || a="$d"
```

Comment: Note that the `=` operator tests for string equality, not numeric equality (i.e. `[[ 05 = 5 ]]` is false).  If you want numeric comparison, use `-eq` instead.

Comment: It's more of a short form for `if/then/else`

Comment: It's a genius way to utilize the short-circuit behavior to get a ternary operator effect :) :) :)

Comment: @XiongChiamiov, your double bracket expression is incorrect. The order of the last 2 assignment operands (`c` and `d`) must be reversed to be equivalent to the `?` operator in the OP's question:  `[[ $b = 5 ]] && a="$d" || a="$c"`.

Comment: why the [[ and ]] ? it works just as well like this : [ $b = 5 ] && a="$c" || a="$d"

Comment: in case it helps anyone, I used the following based off the answer from @ghostdog74 & modified to use an arithmetic context:
`(( 3 > 1 )) && echo "yup" || echo "nooope")`, and thus `answer=$( (( 3 > 1 )) && echo "ouiii" || echo "nooope")` or the shorter `(( 3 > 7 )) && answer="yup" || answer="nop"`

Comment: @StephaneAG You have one closing bracket too much at `(3 > 1))`. The last one should be left off.

Comment: kdubs the documentation recommends to use [[ ]] when doing direct number comparisons. [  ] works better with strings.

Comment: The `cond && op1 || op2` construct has an inherent bug: if `op1` has nonzero exit status for whatever reason, the result will silently become `op2`. [`if cond; then op1; else op2; fi`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25119904/648265) is one line too and doesn't have that defect.

Comment: If you aren't using the exit status of `op1`, you can use `cond && { op1 ||: } || op2`. `:` is equivalent to `true` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224878/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-gnu-bash-builtin -- the `:` is required in POSIX shells, apparently more portable than `true`, but read for more info.)

Comment: I appreciate the warning from @ivan_pozdeev, but I object to calling it a "bug". I would rather state "when using `&&` it is imperative that you understand the meaning of **AND**". The meaning is "both evaluate to true". If `opt1` can be falsey, you should inverse your `cond` if and **only if** `opt2` cannot be falsey. If that is **not** true, your logic **is not** a candidate for `&&` … `||` shorthand/logic and you must use `if` … `then` … `else` longhand/logic.

Comment: How to demonstrate @BrunoBronosky's suggestion: `[[ "foo" == "foo" ]] && echo yes || echo no` behaves as you would expect. Now try `[[ "foo" == "foo" ]] && false || echo no` to simulate op1 failing. oops!

Comment: @GordonDavisson for numeric comparison use ((b == 5)) you can omit the $ inside `((...))` https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic

Comment: You could consider unsiing [bash integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539561/1765658)!  Your answer is cited.

Comment: `?` is `&&`, `:` is `||`

Answer (score 613):

Code:

```
a=$([ "$b" == 5 ] && echo "$c" || echo "$d")
```

Comment: this is better than the others... the point about the tertiary operator is that it's an operator, hence it's proper context is in an expression, hence it must return a value.

Comment: This is the most concise way. Be aware that if the part with `echo "$c"` is an aliased, multi-lined command (like `echo 1; echo 2`), you should enclose it in parentheses.

Comment: This will also capture any output of the tested command, too (yes, in this particular case, we "know" it doesn't produce any).

Comment: This *chain* of operators only behaves like a ternary operator if you are positive that the command after `&&` won't have a non-zero exit status. Otherwise, `a && b || c`  will "unexpectedly" run `c` if `a` succeeds but `b` fails.

Comment: You could consider unsiing [bash integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539561/1765658)!  Your answer is cited.

Comment: several issues with this, starts a subshell, uses `echo` and doesn't quote the result. To be honest this approach is shoehorning the concept of a ternary operator into a language that doesn't have one. If I came across this in the wild I would be bewildered

Answer (score 265):

If the condition is merely checking if a variable is set, there's even a shorter form:

```
a=${VAR:-20}
```

will assign to `a` the value of `VAR` if `VAR` is set, otherwise it will assign it the default value `20` -- this can also be a result of an expression.

This approach is technically called "Parameter Expansion".

Comment: In the case of passing a string parameter with hyphens in it, I had to use quote marks:

`a=${1:-'my-hyphenated-text'}`

Comment: [link for the lazy](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) - there are additional operators than just substitute (`:-`)

Comment: @JustinWrobel - unfortunately no syntax like `${VAR:-yes:-no}`.

Comment: Not what the OP wanted, but just wanted to say thanks for teaching me something new today that fit my scenario perfectly ^_^

Comment: @KenWilliams Actually there is a syntax like that, it uses a second type of parameter expansion, `:+`. You can do `${${VAR:+yes}:-no}`... if `VAR` is set & non-null, this will expand to `yes` and if `VAR` is unset or null it expands to `no`.

Comment: @JoshuaSkrzypek, no, this will not work. `VAR=1; echo "${${VAR:+yes}:-no}"` → `-bash: ${${VAR:+yes}:-no}: bad substitution` and `VAR=; echo "${${VAR:+yes}:-no}"` → `-bash: ${${VAR:+yes}:-no}: bad substitution`

Comment: `${${VAR+yes}:-no}` works for `zsh (5.8)`

Comment: @JulianMehnle  You're totally right, that's a zshism, not a bashism

Answer (score 146):

```
if [[ $b -eq 5 ]]; then a="$c"; else a="$d"; fi
```

The `cond && op1 || op2` expression suggested in other answers has an inherent bug: if `op1` has a nonzero exit status, `op2` silently becomes the result; the error will also not be caught in `-e` mode. So, that expression is only safe to use if `op1` can never fail (e.g., `:`, `true` if a builtin, or variable assignment without any operations that can fail (like division and OS calls)).

Note the `""` quotes. They will prevent translation of all whitespace into single spaces.

Double square brackets as opposed to single ones prevent incorrect operation if `$b` is equal to a `test` operator (e.g. "`-z`"; a workaround with `[` is `[ "x$b" == "xyes" ]` and it only works for string comparison); they also lift the requirement for quoting.

Comment: Great point! I would just like to add that this is exactly the kind of sneaky bug that [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds for you. In this case, the relevant [wiki page](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2015).

Answer (score 62):

```
(( a = b==5 ? c : d )) # string + numeric
```

Comment: This is good for **numeric** comparisons and assignments, but it will give unpredictable results if you use it for string comparisons and assignments.... `(( ))` treats any/all strings as `0`

Comment: This can also be written: `a=$(( b==5 ? c : d ))`

Comment: You could consider unsiing [bash integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539561/1765658)!  Your answer is cited.

Answer (score 44):

```
[ $b == 5 ] && { a=$c; true; } || a=$d
```

This will avoid executing the part after || by accident when the code between && and || fails.

Comment: This will still not catch the error in `-e` mode: `(set -o errexit; [ 5 == 5 ] && { false; true; echo "success"; } || echo "failure"; echo $?; echo "further on";)` -> `success
0
further on`

Comment: Use the `:` bulit-in instead of `true` to save `exec`-ing an external program.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Is there any way to use `&&` .. `||` and still catch a failed command in between them?

Comment: @TomHale No. `&&` and `||` by definition apply to the entire command before them. So, if you have two commands before it (regardless of how they are combined), you cannot apply it to only to one of them and not the other. You _can_ emulate `if`/`then`/`else` logic with flag variables, but why bother if there's `if`/`then`/`else` proper?

Answer (score 35):

We can use following three ways in Shell Scripting for ternary operator :

```
    [ $numVar == numVal ] && resVar="Yop" || resVar="Nop"

Or

    resVar=$([ $numVar == numVal ] && echo "Yop" || echo "Nop")

Or

    (( numVar == numVal ? (resVar=1) : (resVar=0) ))
```

**Update:** Extending the answer for string computations with below ready-to-run example. This is making use of second format mentioned above.

```
$ strVar='abc';resVar=$([[ $strVar == 'abc' ]] && echo "Yop" || echo "Nop");echo $resVar
Yop
$ strVar='aaa';resVar=$([[ $strVar == 'abc' ]] && echo "Yop" || echo "Nop");echo $resVar
Nop
```

Comment: This is actually (the first and second specifically, of these three examples) the most appropriate answer to this question IMHO.

Comment: Each of the suggested ways has limitations/caveats which are not explained. So using this answer is dangerous.

Answer (score 14):

The *let* command supports most of the basic operators one would need:

```
let a=b==5?c:d;
```

Naturally, this works only for assigning variables; it cannot execute other commands.

Comment: it is exactly equivalent to (( ... )), so it is only valid for arithmetic expressions

Answer (score 14):

Here is another option where you only have to specify the variable you're assigning once, and it  doesn't matter whether what your assigning is a string or a number:

```
VARIABLE=`[ test ] && echo VALUE_A || echo VALUE_B`
```

Just a thought. :)

Comment: A major downside: it will also capture the stdout of `[ test ]`. So the construct is only safe to use if you "know" that the command doesn't output anything to stdout.

Comment: Also the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash/3953712#3953712 plus the need to quote and escape quotes inside. The space-tolerant version will look like `VARIABLE="\`[ test ] && echo \"VALUE_A\" || echo \"VALUE_B\"\`"` .

Answer (score 12):

There's also a very similar but simpler syntax for ternary conditionals in bash:

```
a=$(( b == 5 ? 123 : 321  ))
```

Comment: Valid only for "Arithmetic Expansion" yes, i.e. not strings or any `test` results.

Comment: That's right, this syntax is unable to compare non-arithmetical values.

Answer (score 11):

The following seems to work for my use cases:

#### Examples

```
$ tern 1 YES NO                                                                             
YES
    
$ tern 0 YES NO                                                                             
NO
    
$ tern 52 YES NO                                                                            
YES
    
$ tern 52 YES NO 52                                                                         
NO
```

and can be used in a script like so:

```
RESULT=$(tern 1 YES NO)
echo "The result is $RESULT"
```

#### tern

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename "$0")
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

  Returns a ternary result

  usage: BOOLEAN VALUE_IF_TRUE VALUE_IF_FALSE
  
  e.g. 
  
  # YES
  $ME 1 YES NO                                

  # NO
  $ME 0 YES NO

  # NO
  $ME "" YES NO

  # YES
  $ME "STRING THAT ISNT BLANK OR 0" YES NO

  # INFO contains NO
  INFO=\$($ME 0 YES NO)
EOF
)
  echo "$IT"
  echo
  exit
}

if [ "$1" = "help" ] || [ "$1" = '?' ] || [ "$1" = "--help" ] || [ "$1" = "h" ]; then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
  show_help
fi

# Set a default value for what is "false" -> 0
FALSE_VALUE=${4:-0}

function main
{
  if [ "$1" == "$FALSE_VALUE" ] || [ "$1" = '' ]; then
    echo $3
    exit;
  fi;

  echo $2
}

main "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

Comment: Very explanatory. Very complete. Very verbose. Three things I like. ;-)

Comment: is `tern` part of Bash?  Mac doesn't seem to have it

Comment: hey @太極者無極而生 - that's the name of the bash script - save that "tern" section above to a file named "tern", then run `chmod 700 tern` in the same folder. Now you'll have a `tern` command in your terminal

Comment: I quoted your answer in [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539561/1765658).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a general solution, that

- works with string tests as well
- feels rather like an expression
- avoids any subtle side effects when the condition fails

Test with numerical comparison

```
a=$(if [ "$b" -eq 5 ]; then echo "$c"; else echo "$d"; fi)
```

Test with String comparison

```
a=$(if [ "$b" = "5" ]; then echo "$c"; else echo "$d"; fi)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(ping -c1 localhost&>/dev/null) && { echo "true"; } || {  echo "false"; }
```

Comment: This solution has the same defect [ivan_pozdeev describes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3953645#comment73915813_3953666) above where for this solution, `echo "false"` may occur when `ping` is successful, but where, for some reason, however unlikely, the `echo "true"` part returns a non-zero exit status (see [ShellCheck SC2015](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015)).

To `echo "false"` only when `ping` fails, regardless of `echo "true"`’s exit status, move the first grouping brace `{` to the head: `{ (ping -c1 localhost&>/dev/null) && echo "true"; } || { echo "false"; }`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this if you want similar syntax

```
a=$(( $((b==5)) ? c : d ))
```

Comment: This works only with integers.  You can write it more simply as `a=$(((b==5) ? : c : d))` - `$((...))` is needed only when we want to assign the result of the arithmetic to another variable.

Answer (score 4):

Some people have already presented some nice alternatives.  I wanted to get the syntax as close as possible, so I wrote a function named `?`.

This allows for the syntax:

```sh
[[ $x -eq 1 ]]; ? ./script1 : ./script2
# or
? '[[ $x -eq 1 ]]' ./script1 : ./script2
```

In both cases, the `:` is optional.  All arguments that have spaces, the values must be quoted since it runs them with `eval`.

If the `<then>` or `<else>` clauses aren't commands, the function `echo`s the proper value.

```sh
./script; ? Success! : "Failure :("
```

##### The function

```sh
?() {
  local lastRet=$?
  if [[ $1 == --help || $1 == -? ]]; then
    echo $'\e[37;1mUsage:\e[0m
  ? [<condition>] <then> [:] <else>

If \e[37;1m<then>\e[0m and/or \e[37;1m<else>\e[0m are not valid commands, then their values are
printed to stdOut, otherwise they are executed.  If \e[37;1m<condition>\e[0m is not
specified, evaluates the return code ($?) of the previous statement.

\e[37;1mExamples:\e[0m
  myVar=$(? "[[ $x -eq 1 ]] foo bar)
  \e[32;2m# myVar is set to "foo" if x is 1, else it is set to "bar"\e[0m

  ? "[[ $x = *foo* ]] "cat hello.txt" : "cat goodbye.txt"
  \e[32;2m# runs cat on "hello.txt" if x contains the word "foo", else runs cat on
  # "goodbye.txt"\e[0m

  ? "[[ $x -eq 1 ]] "./script1" "./script2"; ? "Succeeded!" "Failed :("
  \e[32;2m# If x = 1, runs script1, else script2.  If the run script succeeds, prints
  # "Succeeded!", else prints "failed".\e[0m'
    return
  elif ! [[ $# -eq 2 || $# -eq 3 || $# -eq 4 && $3 == ':' ]]; then
    1>&2 echo $'\e[37;1m?\e[0m requires 2 to 4 arguments

\e[37;1mUsage\e[0m: ? [<condition>] <then> [:] <else>
Run \e[37;1m? --help\e[0m for more details'
    return 1
  fi

  local cmd

  if [[ $# -eq 2 || $# -eq 3 && $2 == ':' ]]; then
    cmd="[[ $lastRet -eq 0 ]]"
  else
    cmd="$1"
    shift
  fi

  if [[ $2 == ':' ]]; then
    eval "set -- '$1' '$3'"
  fi

  local result=$(eval "$cmd" && echo "$1" || echo "$2")
  if command -v ${result[0]} &> /dev/null; then
    eval "${result[@]}"
  else
    echo "${result[@]}"
  fi
}
```

Obviously if you want the script to be shorter, you can remove the help text.

**EDIT**: I was unaware that `?` acts as a placeholder character in a file name.  Rather than matching any number of characters like `*`, it matches exactly one character.  So, if you have a one-character file in your working directory, bash will try to run the filename as a command.  I'm not sure how to get around this.  I thought using `command "?" ...args` might work but, no dice.

Answer (score 3):

#### Simplest ternary

```sh
brew list | grep -q bat && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

This example will determine if you used home`brew` to install `bat` or not yet

If true you will see "yes"

If false you will see "no"

I added the `-q` to suppress the `grep`ped string output here, so you only see "yes" or "no"

#### Really the pattern you seek is this

```sh
doSomethingAndCheckTruth && echo 'yes' || echo 'no'
```

Tested with `bash` and `zsh`

Comment: See this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash#comment73915813_3953666). If the `&&` fails, then the `||` will be run, which is not quite the desired behavior.

Comment: My answer here also has some ternary examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62527825/1783588

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

1- Use if then else in one line, it is possible.

```
if [[ "$2" == "raiz" ]] || [[ "$2" == '.' ]]; then pasta=''; else pasta="$2"; fi
```

2- Write a function like this:

```
 # Once upon a time, there was an 'iif' function in MS VB ...

function iif(){
  # Echoes $2 if 1,banana,true,etc and $3 if false,null,0,''
  case $1 in ''|false|FALSE|null|NULL|0) echo $3;;*) echo $2;;esac
}
```

use inside script like this

```
result=`iif "$expr" 'yes' 'no'`

# or even interpolating:
result=`iif "$expr" "positive" "negative, because $1 is not true"`
```

3- Inspired in the case answer, a more flexible and one line use is:

```
 case "$expr" in ''|false|FALSE|null|NULL|0) echo "no...$expr";;*) echo "yep $expr";;esac

 # Expression can be something like:     
   expr=`expr "$var1" '>' "$var2"`
```

Answer (score 2):

to answer to : `int a = (b == 5) ? c : d;`

just write:

```sh
b=5
c=1
d=2
let a="(b==5)?c:d"

echo $a # 1

b=6;
c=1;
d=2;
let a="(b==5)?c:d"

echo $a # 2
```

remember that " expression " is equivalent to $(( expression ))

Answer (score 2):

## Two more answers

Here's some ways of thinking about this

### bash integer variables

In addition to, [dutCh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3955920/1765658), [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953712/1765658) and [ghostdog74](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953666/1765658)'s corrects answers and because this question is regarding *integer* **and** tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

> Is there a way to do something like this
>
> ```
> int a = (b == 5) ? c : d;
> ```

There is a nice and proper way to work with integers under bash:

```
declare -i b=' RANDOM % 3 + 4 ' c=100 d=50 a='  b == 5 ? c : d '; echo $b '-->' $a
```

The output line from this command should by one of:

```
4 --> 50
5 --> 100
6 --> 50
```

Of course, declaring *integer* type of variable is to be done once:

```
declare -i a b c d
c=100 d=50 b=RANDOM%3+4
a=' b == 5 ? c : d '
echo $a $b
100 5
b=12 a=b==5?c:d
echo $a $b
50 12
```

Note: This syntax is ***recommanded***. Declaring property of a variable, then assigning a value is better to be done separately.

#### Digression: Using a string as a *math function*:

```
mathString=' b == 5 ? c : d '
b=5 a=$mathString
echo $a $b
100 5

b=1 a=$mathString 
echo $a $b
50 1
```

### Based on *parameter expansion* and *indirection*

Following answers from [Brad Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512445/1765658) and [druid62](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250092/1765658), here is a way **not limited to integer**:

```
c=50 d=100 ar=([5]=c)
read -p 'Enter B: ' b
e=${ar[b]:-d};echo ${!e}
```

- If `b==5`, then `ar[b]` is `c` and *indirection* do `c` is `50`.
- Else `ar[any value other than 5]` is empty, so *parameter expansion* will default to `d`, where *indirection* give `100`.

#### Same demo using an array instead of an integer

```
ternArrayDemo(){
    local -a c d e ar
    local b
    c=(foo bar) d=(foo bar baz) e=(empty) ar=([5]=c [2]=d)
    b=${ar[$1]:-e}
    b+=[@]      # For array indirection
    printf ' - %s\n' "${!b}"
}
```

Then

```
ternArrayDemo 0
 - empty
ternArrayDemo 2 
 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
ternArrayDemo 4
 - empty
ternArrayDemo 5
 - foo
 - bar
ternArrayDemo 6
 - empty
```

#### Or using *associative arrays*

```
ternAssocArrayDemo(){
     local -a c d e
     local -A ar
     local b
     c=(foo bar) d=(foo bar baz) e=(empty)
     ar=([foo]=c[@] [bar]=d[@] [baz]=d[-1])
     b=${ar[$1]:-e[@]}
     printf ' - %s\n' "${!b}"
}
```

Then

```
ternAssocArrayDemo hello
 - empty
ternAssocArrayDemo foo
 - foo
 - bar
ternAssocArrayDemo bar
 - foo
 - bar
 - baz
ternAssocArrayDemo baz
 - baz
```

Comment: Regarding `declare -i b=' RANDOM % 3 + 4 '`: TIL that in *bash*, when a [variable is declared as an integer](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-declare), then [the value assigned to it is evaluated as an arithmetic expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html).

Comment: @Abdull Correct!

Answer (score 1):

This is much like [Vladimir's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953712/117471). If your "ternary" is a case of "if true, string, if false, empty", then you can simply do:

```
$ c="it was five"
$ b=3
$ a="$([[ $b -eq 5 ]] && echo "$c")"
$ echo $a

$ b=5
$ a="$([[ $b -eq 5 ]] && echo "$c")"
$ echo $a
it was five
```

Answer (score 1):

A string-oriented alternative, that uses an array:

```
spec=(IGNORE REPLACE)
for p in {13..15}; do
  echo "$p: ${spec[p==14]}";
done
```

which outputs:

```
13: IGNORE
14: REPLACE
15: IGNORE
```

Comment: I quoted your answer in [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73539561/1765658).

Answer (score 1):

What about such approach:

```
# any your function
function check () {
    echo 'checking...';

    # Change the following to 'true' to emulate a successful execution.
    # Note: You can replace check function with any function you wish.
    # Be aware in linux false and true are funcitons themselves. see 'help false' for instance.
    false; 
}

# double check pattern
check && echo 'update' \
    || check || echo 'create';
```

See how conditional statements works in the RxJs (i.e. filter pipe).
Yes, it is code duplication but more functional approach from my point of view.

Answer (score 0):

The top answer `[[ $b = 5 ]] && a="$c" || a="$d"` should only be used if you are certain there will be no error after the `&&`, otherwise it will incorrectly excute the part after the `||`.

To solve that problem I wrote a ternary function that behaves as it should and it even uses the `?` and `:` operators:

**Edit - new solution**

Here is my new solution that does not use `$IFS` nor `ev(a/i)l`.

```
function executeCmds()
{
    declare s s1 s2 i j k
    declare -A cmdParts
    declare pIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    declare results=($(echo "$1" | grep -oP '{ .*? }'))
    IFS=$pIFS
    s="$1"
    for ((i=0; i < ${#results[@]}; i++)); do
        s="${s/${results[$i]}/'\0'}"
        results[$i]="${results[$i]:2:${#results[$i]}-3}"
        results[$i]=$(echo ${results[$i]%%";"*})
    done
    s="$s&&"
    let cmdParts[t]=0
    while :; do
        i=${cmdParts[t]}
        let cmdParts[$i,t]=0
        s1="${s%%"&&"*}||"
        while :; do
            j=${cmdParts[$i,t]}
            let cmdParts[$i,$j,t]=0
            s2="${s1%%"||"*};"
            while :; do
                cmdParts[$i,$j,${cmdParts[$i,$j,t]}]=$(echo ${s2%%";"*})
                s2=${s2#*";"}
                let cmdParts[$i,$j,t]++
                [[ $s2 ]] && continue
                break
            done
            s1=${s1#*"||"}
            let cmdParts[$i,t]++
            [[ $s1 ]] && continue
            break
        done
        let cmdParts[t]++
        s=${s#*"&&"}
        [[ $s ]] && continue
        break
    done
    declare lastError=0
    declare skipNext=false
    for ((i=0; i < ${cmdParts[t]}; i++ )) ; do
        let j=0
        while :; do
            let k=0
            while :; do
                if $skipNext; then
                    skipNext=false
                else
                    if [[ "${cmdParts[$i,$j,$k]}" == "\0" ]]; then
                         executeCmds "${results[0]}" && lastError=0 || lastError=1
                         results=("${results[@]:1}")
                    elif [[ "${cmdParts[$i,$j,$k]:0:1}" == "!" || "${cmdParts[$i,$j,$k]:0:1}" == "-" ]]; then
                        [ ${cmdParts[$i,$j,$k]} ] && lastError=0 || lastError=1
                    else
                        ${cmdParts[$i,$j,$k]}
                        lastError=$?
                    fi
                    if (( k+1 < cmdParts[$i,$j,t] )); then
                        skipNext=false
                    elif (( j+1 < cmdParts[$i,t] )); then
                        (( lastError==0 )) && skipNext=true || skipNext=false
                    elif (( i+1 < cmdParts[t] )); then
                        (( lastError==0 )) && skipNext=false || skipNext=true
                    fi
                fi
                let k++
                [[ $k<${cmdParts[$i,$j,t]} ]] || break
            done
            let j++
            [[ $j<${cmdParts[$i,t]} ]] || break
        done
    done
    return $lastError
}

function t()
{
    declare commands="$@"
    find="$(echo ?)"
    replace='?'
    commands="${commands/$find/$replace}"
    readarray -d '?' -t statement <<< "$commands"
    condition=${statement[0]}
    readarray -d ':' -t statement <<< "${statement[1]}"
    success="${statement[0]}"
    failure="${statement[1]}"
    executeCmds "$condition" || { executeCmds "$failure"; return; }
    executeCmds "$success"
}
```

`executeCmds` separates each command individually, apart from the ones that should be skipped due to the `&&` and `||` operators. It uses `[]` whenever a command starts with `!` or a flag.

There are two ways to pass commands to it:

1. Pass the individual commands unquoted but be sure to quote `;`, `&&`, and `||` operators.

```
t ls / ? ls qqq '||' echo aaa : echo bbb '&&' ls qq
```

2. Pass all the commands quoted:

```
t 'ls /a ? ls qqq || echo aaa : echo bbb && ls qq'
```

*NB* I found no way to pass in `&&` and `||` operators as parameters unquoted, as they are illegal characters for function names and aliases, and I found no way to override bash operators.

**Old solution - uses ev(a/i)l**

```
function t()
{
    pIFS=$IFS
    IFS="?"
    read condition success <<< "$@"
    IFS=":"
    read success failure <<< "$success"
    IFS=$pIFS
    eval "$condition" || { eval "$failure" ; return; }
    eval "$success"
}
t ls / ? ls qqq '||' echo aaa : echo bbb '&&' ls qq
t 'ls /a ? ls qqq || echo aaa : echo bbb && ls qq'
```