# Is there an inline-if with assignment (ternary conditional) in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ternary operator (?:) in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash)

If this were AS3 or Java, I would do the following:

```
fileName = dirName + "/" + (useDefault ? defaultName : customName) + ".txt";
```

But in shell, that seems needlessly complicated, requiring several lines of code, as well as quite a bit of repeated code.

```
if [ $useDefault ]; then
    fileName="$dirName/$defaultName.txt"
else
    fileName="$dirName/$customName.txt"
fi
```

You could compress that all into one line, but that sacrifices clarity immensely.

Is there any better way of writing an inline `if` with variable assignment in shell?

Comment: William Purcell's answer is less direct than mine, but if the assumption that `$useDefault` controls whether to use the default name or not, it might be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer to quote everything properly.

Comment: ```fileName="$dirName/$([ $useDefault ] && echo "$defaultName" || echo "$customName").txt"``` I think this is as close to ```?:``` as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `?:` conditional operator in the shell, but you could make the code a little less redundant like this:

```
if [ $useDefault ]; then
    tmpname="$defaultName"
else
    tmpname="$customName"
fi
fileName="$dirName/$tmpname.txt"
```

Or you could write your own shell function that acts like the `?:` operator:

```
cond() {
    if [ "$1" ] ; then
        echo "$2"
    else
        echo "$3"
    fi
}

fileName="$dirname/$(cond "$useDefault" "$defaultName" "$customName").txt"
```

though that's probably overkill (and it evaluates all three arguments).

Thanks to Gordon Davisson for pointing out in comments that quotes nest within `$(...)`.

Comment: I really like the `cond` function, which is the reason I accepted the answer, though the first solution does save repetitious code as well.

Comment: You should leave the `$(cond ... )` inside the double-quotes (i.e. `fileName="$dirname/$(cond "$useDefault" "$defaultName" "$customName").txt"`) -- that'll prevent some almost-certainly-unwanted extra parsing on the string cond returns.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: I thought about that, but it leaves the variable references `$useDefault` et al outside the quotes. I'm not sure there's a good solution.

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's not a problem; quotes nest with `$()`, so `$useDefault` will be treated as double-quoted either way.

Answer (score 19):

Just write:

```
fileName=${customName:-$defaultName}.txt
```

It's not quite the same as what you have, since it does not check `useDefault`.  Instead, it just checks if `customName` is set.  Instead of setting `useDefault` when you want to use the default, you simply unset `customName`.

Comment: Could you provide more information on this `:-` operator? (or at least some name for it that I can search Google with)

Comment: Just search for `:-` in the bash man page.  Any `sh` documentation will describe this under headings like `parameter expansion`.

Comment: For `bash`, see [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion); for POSIX shell, see [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: great introduction and then building up to it: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value

Comment: I like this one, it's like the // operator ("Undefined-or") in Perl which I always use for assigning default values.