# assign the value if empty in shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a script under Unix system.

Is there any way to assign value like this:

```
x=($1 == "") ? 3 : 4
```

if `$1` is empty we will assign value "3" to x, otherwise the value "4"

Comment: What you're looking for is called ternary operator, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash

Comment: Specifically **ignore** the accepted answer and look at the [next answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12691027/258523).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with either `let` or `(())` bash constructions. For example:

```
a=1
let "b = a == 1 ? 2 : 3"
echo $b
```

For further details see `man 1 bash`

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers are not usually clear for others.

Comment: Please clarify, what kind of comment do you expect? Author asks "how can i do this?", I sure can add explanatory line "You can do it with following construction:", but does it really increase clarity of the answer?

Comment: Well simply providing the answer without explaining why it works isn't enlightening for others nor does it encourage understanding. The answer may be clear but is it clear how the answer was found? It's like giving the answer to an equation without the whole process to get to it or at least some pointers.