# Conditional if operator in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-operator

Set the value of `myval` to `$1` if it is not empty. If it is empty, set value of `myval` to `val`. Is this syntax correct in bash?

```
#!/bin/bash

val=5
myval=""
if [ "$val" != "" ]; then
    myval=("$1" == "" ? $val : $1)
fi
echo $myval
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is incorrect, but there is a parameter expansion operator to do what you want.

```
myval=${1:-$val}
```