# If errexit is on, how do I run a command that might fail and get its exit code?

Tags: bash

All of my scripts have errexit turned on; that is, I run `set -o errexit`. However, sometimes I want to run commands like `grep`, but want to continue execution of my script even if the command fails.

How do I do this? That is, how can I get the exit code of a command into a variable without killing my whole script?

I could turn errexit off, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Keeping `set -e` off [is really the best thing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Automatic error handling is only more benefit than cost when its behavior is consistent, predictable and reliable, and `set -e` is none of those things: It varies between shells, between *releases* of the same shell, and has numerous hidden surprises: For instance, if you're writing a function, whether `errexit` takes effect on an error on any command within it depends on whether *the exit status of the function itself* is being tested.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The only alternatives are the shell running off the rails after an error, ruining my servers, or adding `|| exit $?` after each command. The code maintenance overhead due to `-e` drawbacks that you describe is incomparably smaller than that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, first, it's just `|| exit` (when not in a function context where `|| return` is desirable instead); `$?` is the default exit status. Second, `foo || exit` after each and every command is *clearly not* the right thing -- if it were, the behavior of `set -e` wouldn't have such a large (and varied, between shells) set of exceptions in its behavior, making its behavior contextually-sensitive and hard to predict. For instance, `(( ++count )) || exit` is clearly wrong since it exits when incrementing `count` from `0` to `1`, yet `set -e; (( ++count ))` does precisely that.

Comment: ...or, rather, does precisely that *in some versions of bash but not others*, which further reinforces my point: If you can't rely on the behavior on `set -e` to be consistent, you're better off putting in explicit `|| die "error message here"` calls (`die` being a conventional name for a function that prints an error before exiting), such that you *can* ensure consistency.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `errexit` will only cause the script to terminate if the command that fails is "untested".  Per `man sh` on FreeBSD:

```
         Exit immediately if any untested command fails in non-interactive
         mode.  The exit status of a command is considered to be explic-
         itly tested if the command is part of the list used to control an
         if, elif, while, or until; if the command is the left hand oper-
         and of an ``&&'' or ``||'' operator; or if the command is a pipe-
         line preceded by the ! keyword.
```

So .. if you were thinking of using a construct like this:

```
grep -q something /path/to/somefile
retval=$?
if [ $retval -eq 0 ]; then
  do_something  # found
else
  do_something_else  # not found
fi
```

you should instead use a construct like this:

```
if grep -q something /path/to/somefile; then
  do_something  # found
else
  do_something_else  # not found
fi
```

The existence of the `if` keyword makes the grep command ***tested***, thus unaffected by `errexit`. And this way takes less typing.

Of course, if you REALLY need the exit value in a variable, there's nothing stopping you from using `$?`:

```
if grep -q something /path/to/somefile; then
  do_something  # found
else
  unnecessary=$?
  do_something $unnecessary  # not found
fi
```

Comment: Great answer. Note the following "trap" expanding on the latter example: `if ! false; then e=$?; echo $e; else echo ok; fi` prints `0` as the `!` operator introduces another evaluation, while `if false; then echo ok; else e=$?; echo $e; fi`prints `1` as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to achieve this: you can "turn off" `set -o errexit` for some lines of code, and then turn it on again when you decide:

```
set +e  #disables set -o errexit
grep -i something file.txt
rc="$?" #capturing the return code for last command
set -e #reenables set -o errexit
```

Another option would be the following:

```
grep -i something file.txt || rc="$?"
```

That would allow you to capture the return code on the variable `rc`, without interrupting your script. You could even extend this last option to capture and process the return code on the same line without risking to trigger an exit:

```
grep -i something file.txt || rc="$?" && echo rc="$?" > somefile.txt && command || :
```

The last bit `||:` will guarantee that the line above always returns a return code = 0 (true).

Comment: In fact, it's the use of the or bars (`||`) that causes this to work, not the echo of the variable to a text file. The exit status of a command is considered to be explicitly tested if it's on the left hand side of `||`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44081089/1072112) for the full text from the man page.

Comment: Yes, I did not state otherwise (that the use of "or" `||` is what makes it "work"). However, my comment above is correct, because if the last command fails (in my example `echo "$rc" > file.txt`), that would still trigger the exit.

Comment: I think the only problem with your comment is that it doesn't make clear that the command appearing after the semicolon isn't actually part of the same command line containing the `||`, it's an entirely different command regardless of its "position" to the right of or below the line in question.  If writing to `file.txt` generates a permission error, that's unrelated to the issue in the question.

Comment: @ghoti OK, I see your point now. I changed my answer for sake of clarity, and also added some improvements.

Answer (score 4):

The most compact and least repetitive form I can think of:

```
<command> && rc=$? || rc=$?
```

A form without variable name repetition -- `rc=$(<command> && echo $? || echo $?)` -- has an expression rvalue but would also capture the stdout of `<command>`<sup>1</sup>. So, it's only safe if you "know" that `<command>` has no normal output.

Using the `a && b || c` construct [is safe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash/25119904#25119904) because `rc=$?` and `$(echo $?)` can never fail.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Sure, you can work around this by fiddling with file descriptors, but that'd make the construct long-winded and inconvenient as a standard</sub>