# In bash check piped input matches string exactly

Tags: bash

How can I check that the piped input matches a string exactly, preferably in a single line?

For example:

```
some command | <check that equals "foo" exactly>
```

Where it would return an exit code of 0 if it was an exact match.

I tried using grep, but I don't want an exit code of 0 if the input was "foobar" for example, only if it is exactly "foo"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the output.

```
[[ $(some command) == "foo" ]]
```

Comment: is it possible to do it on the one line? something like `some command | = "foo"`?

Comment: @brad you may want to check out the [ternary operator in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how that would look for my situation? It is still unclear to me after reading over that link

Comment: @brad Just remove the `if then fi` and it's a one-liner.

Comment: `[[ $(printf 'foo\n') == "foo" ]] && echo an unexpected false positive`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

`some command | cmp <(echo "expected output (plus a newline by echo)")`

Here, `cmp` will compare the content of its standard input (because only one file is given) and that of the process substitution "file" `<(…)`, which in this case is the command `echo "…"`. Note, that `echo` will append a newline to its output, which can be suppressed with `-n` or by using `printf` instead.

You may also wish to `--silence` the output of `cmp` (see `man cmp`).

The `diff` command also operates in a similar fashion to `cmp`.

Another solution might be to use `grep`, but there is no ultimate way to make sure it "matches a string **exactly**", depending on newlines involved in `some command` output.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using awk:

```
some command | awk '$0 == "foo" {print $0;}' | grep -q "" && echo "Match"
```