# remove a subfolder with bash if it exsits

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

I have a subfolder of something like:

```
USERS = /opt/users/
```

I want to delete a subfolder of /opt/users without defining a new variable like:

```
if [ -d $USERS/phones ] && [-d $USERS/emails]; then
     rm -Rf $USERS/phones 
     rm -RF $USERS/emails
else 
     echo "Folder does not exist, continuing the process"
fi
```

The question is can you suggest some smarter way or is good enough? I don't know how to handle if one of the folders is not existing or if I have another && condition? and the two commands rm -Rf I am not sure of the way it looks kinda ugly. Any recommendations?

Comment: `-f` will cause `rm` to ignore nonexisting folders, so there's no need for those extra check, unless you have to show that log for each separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, some general bash tips:

- Consider quoting strings
  [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
- No spaces around `=`
  [Command not found error in Bash variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268104/command-not-found-error-in-bash-variable-assignment)

---

That said, lets take a closer look at [`rm -f`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rm):

> `-f`, `--force`
>
> **ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt**

So there's no need to add extra checks if the folder exists.

You can change the code to:

```sh
USERS="/opt/users/"
rm -Rf "$USERS/phones"
rm -RF "$USERS/emails"
```

---

If you want to add a `echo` for each file that does not exist, we'll need to check if it exist:
[How can I check if a directory exists in a Bash shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script)

Using a [short `if/else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash), the code could look something like this:

```sh
USERS="/opt/users/"
[[ -d "$USERS/phones" ]] && rm -Rf "$USERS/phones" || echo '/phones does not exists'
[[ -d "$USERS/emails" ]] && rm -Rf "$USERS/emails" || echo '/emails does not exists'
```

---

The above code can be simplified by using [array's](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html):

```sh
declare -a folders=("phones" "emails")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   [[ -d "$USERS/$i" ]] && rm -Rf "$USERS/$i" || echo "/$i does not exists"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation on OP's code assuming there could be a variable number of subdirectories to remove:

```
users=/opt/users/                        # refrain from using ALL CAPS for user-defined variables
rmlist=(phones emails 'other schtuff')   # array of subdirectory names

for subdir in "${rmlist[@]}"
do
    [[ -d "${users}/${subdir}" ]] && rm -Rf "${users}/${subdir}" && continue
    echo "Folder ${users}/${subdir} does not exist, continuing the process"
fi
```