# Set an env variable using bash command that checks for existence of input variable

Tags: github-actions

[I've been reading about expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions).

I need to create an env var that all jobs in a workflow can reference that, in English, checks for the existence of `${{ inputs.db_schema }}` and if it exists, use it, otherwise set it to 'prod'.

Tried (borrows from JWLs solution on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953645/ternary-operator-in-bash)):

```
env:
  db_schema: ${{ ${{inputs.db_schema}} :-'prod }}
```

This returned an error when I tried to run:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yaml (Line: 17, Col: 14): Unexpected symbol: '${{inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: ${{inputs.db_schema .github/workflows/update-sk4-caller.yaml (Line: 18, Col: 16): Unexpected symbol: '${{inputs'. Located at position 1 within expression: ${{inputs.update_date
```

How can I create an env variable that can be used by all jobs in a workflow where the value is either what exists in `${{inputs.db_schema}}` else if that input doesn't exist then 'prod'?

[EDIT]

Adding a more complete example of what I"m trying to do. Here's a piece of my workflow:

```
name: MyWorkflow
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      db_schema:
        required: true
        type: string
        default: US.DATA_SCIENCE
  schedule:
    - cron:  '10 3 * * *' # daily at ten past 3am

env:
  db_schema: ${{inputs.db_schema || 'US.DATA_SCIENCE'}}

jobs:
  check-env-vars:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: check env vars
        run: |
          echo ${{ env.db_schema }}
  update-clicks:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/update-clicks.yaml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      db_schema: ${{ env.db_schema }}
```

I need to pass a value to `db_schema` within the `with` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing access to GitHub Actions context and shell parameter expansion. You might be able to do something like

```yaml
  db_schema: ${{ inputs.db_schema || 'prod' }}
```

or if you access `db_schema` in a shell script, you could use

```yaml
  db_schema: ${{ inputs.db_schema }}
```

and then access via

```bash
${db_schema:-prod}
```

Comment: just `github.event.inputs.db_schema` in case

Comment: @Matteo `inputs` is accessible directly, access via `github.event` is there to maintain compatibility (see [here](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-10-github-actions-inputs-unified-across-manual-and-reusable-workflows/)).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried the first suggestion but get error: "The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/update-sk4-caller.yaml (Line: 32, Col: 18): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.db_schema .github/workflows/...r.yaml (Line: 37, Col: 18): Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.db_schema". For your second suggestion, the issue is I need to pass this to a `with`. Can I use an expression when passing a value within a `with` do you know?

Comment: I added a more complete snippet from my yaml, I'm hoping my goal is more clear after that.

Comment: Expressions are evaluated before anything else, so IMO you should be able to use `db_schema: ${{ inputs.db_schema || 'US.DATA_SCIENCE' }}` in the call to your reusable workflow, no `env` required.