# nx:run-commands default args values

Tags: json, nrwl, nx.dev

i have react library created inside nx mono repo using this version

`nx: 15.6.3`

i've added inside the packages/my-library command to run multiple commands

`generate react component`
`generate react-stories`

using these plugins `@nrwl/react:component` - `@nrwl/react:component-story`

this is the target

```json
"generate-atom": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "nx g @nrwl/react:component --project=core --style=@emotion/styled --export --directory=atoms/{args.group} --name={args.name}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true,
            "bgColor": "bgBlue"
          },
          {
            "command": "nx g @nrwl/react:component-story --project=core --componentPath=atoms/{args.group || 'common'}/{args.name}/{args.name}.tsx",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          }
        ],
        "cwd": "packages/core",
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
```

the components is been created inside when i call this target from nx
`packages/core/src/atoms/undefined/button`

this is the command i'm using
`npx nx run core:generate-atom --args="--name=button"`

any idea how can we default the value of `group` if was not passed?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the combination of **Args Interpolation** by `nx:run-commands` and **Shell Parameter Expansion**, as follows:

```
    "generate-atom": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "command": "nx g @nrwl/react:component --project=core --style=@emotion/styled --export --directory=atoms/{args.group} --name={args.name}",
            "forwardAllArgs": true,
            "bgColor": "bgBlue"
          },
          {
            "command": "nx g @nrwl/react:component-story --project=core --componentPath=atoms/${\"{args.group}\"/undefined/common}/{args.name}/{args.name}.tsx",
            "forwardAllArgs": true
          }
        ],
        "cwd": "packages/core",
        "parallel": false
      }
    },
```

In the above sample, `nx:run-commands` executor will replace any occurrences of `/{args\.([^}]+)}/g` regex with the corresponding value, passed to the command as an arg, where missing args will be treated as `undefined`. So, the resulting command passed to Shell would look like `${"undefined"/undefined/common}`, where we use **Shell Parameter Expansion** to match it against `"undefined"` and replace it with `"common"`.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR the answer:

```bash
bash -c \"nx g @nrwl/react:component-story --project=core --componentPath=atoms/$([[ {args.group} = undefined ]] && echo common || echo {args.group})/{args.name}/{args.name}.tsx
```

### The explanation:

Nx's run-command uses node's `child_process.exec` under the hood ([see source code](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/blob/master/packages/nx/src/executors/run-commands/run-commands.impl.ts)).

```
const childProcess = exec(commandConfig.command, {
  maxBuffer: LARGE_BUFFER,
  env: processEnv(color),
  cwd,
});
```

It unfortunately doesn't play nice with shell interpolation (in my experience). To give the simplest possible example, executing `exec('echo $0', (error, stdout) => console.log(stdout)` prints `$0` instead of the shell as it's supposed to.

To work around this, I've taken to add `bash -c "<your actual command here>"`.

The next step to setting the default value is using the ternary operator from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3953712/20418838) to print the wanted value:

```bash
[[ {args.group} = undefined ]] && echo <your default value> || echo {args.group}
```

The javascript equivalent would be:

```js
args.group === "undefined" ? <your default value> : args.group
```

You can then place it in a subshell to get back the wanted value:

```bash
$([[ {args.group} = undefined ]] && echo <your default value> || echo {args.group})
```

And finally use its result in your command like so:

```bash
bash -c \"nx g @nrwl/react:component-story --project=core --componentPath=atoms/$([[ {args.group} = undefined ]] && echo common || echo {args.group})/{args.name}/{args.name}.tsx
```

This is pretty hard to read, but I haven't found a more concise way that works.