# Triggering post-checkout hook after "git checkout -b" command

Tags: git, githooks

Same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011557/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-hook-after-a-new-branch-has-been-checked-out-in-git) before however both answers didn't help me much.

I couldn't get my `post-checkout` hook to differ `git checkout` from `git checkout -b` command as `$1` (sha1 of previous HEAD) and `$2` (sha1 of new HEAD) are same for both calls.

Here is my post-checkout script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "old HEAD: $1"
echo "new HEAD: $2"
echo "checkout type: $3"
```

I executed following commands:

```
> ozgur@ozgurv:~/project (master)$ git checkout -b new_branch
old HEAD: e86423aa9f45053cb45b8ec15d463bb9684526a2
new HEAD: e86423aa9f45053cb45b8ec15d463bb9684526a2
checkout type: 1

> ozgur@ozgurv:~/project (new_branch)$ git checkout my_branch
old HEAD: e86423aa9f45053cb45b8ec15d463bb9684526a2
new HEAD: e86423aa9f45053cb45b8ec15d463bb9684526a2
checkout type: 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to execute the logic in `post-checkout` hook only when a new local branch is created, not when it is checked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really tell the difference, in a post-checkout hook.<sup>1</sup>  In any case you might not *want* to try to tell the difference.  Consider:

```
$ git branch newbr     # make a new branch
$ git checkout newbr   # and now check it out
```

It probably makes sense to do whatever you would have done for `git checkout -b newbr` here, and if so, checking for the `-b` flag (if you can get it to work) is probably counterproductive.  (Consider as well `git checkout feature` when `origin/feature` exists and local branch `feature` does not, which creates `feature` as a new branch that tracks `origin/feature`, even though again there is no `-b` flag.)

Let's look at this again, and I'll suggest a different approach:

> only when a new local branch is created

What if, in your hook, you kept a list of "all seen-so-far local branches" saved in a file?  (Perhaps `.git/ozgur/branchlist` would be a reasonable place to keep this.  We want something that follows the repository around, that git itself is unlikely to use.)  Then, if the checkout is a branch-style checkout (`$3` is `1`), compare the current branch with the list:

```
git_dir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) || exit 1
branchlist=$git_dir/ozgur/branchlist
if [ "$3" = 1 ]; then
    # Checked out a branch - what branch are we on now?
    # (Skip rest of code if we're on a detached HEAD.)
    curbranch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) || return
    # Is $curbranch in our branch list?  Create empty
    # branch list first if needed.  Can just "touch" but
    # this avoids changing the mod-time unnecessarily.
    [ -f $branchlist ] || : > $branchlist
    if ! grep "^$curbranch$" $branchlist > /dev/null; then
        echo "switching to as-yet-unvisited-branch $curbranch"
        echo $curbranch >> $branchlist  # now we've visited it
    fi
fi
```

This still has a bit of a flaw: if you delete a branch, it may remain in the branchlist file.  We could fix that by filtering away deleted branches fairly regularly (compare the `$branchlist` contents to appropriate `git for-each-ref refs/heads` output), perhaps in additional git hooks as well.  But it might suffice for your purposes as-is.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, there *is* a way to tell, at least on systems that will let you look at a process tree, and look at their command arguments.  From the hook, find your parent `git checkout` process and see if it has a `-b` flag.  But then it doesn't work on the two-step `git branch ...; git checkout` sequence, nor on branches automatically created from an upstream branch.