# Git post-checkout hook on windows

Tags: windows, git, githooks

I installed **git 2.28.0** on windows.
In fact, i can't find `post-checkout.sample` hook in the hooks repository under `/.git` repository.
Is `post-checkout.sample` hook supported on windows ?
When i installed the same version of git on linux i found the `post-checkout.sample` hook.
I even tried with the **git 2.23.0** version and i had the same problem.
[image: hooks on windows]

I tried to create `post-checkout` that print a simple message "hello". But it doesn't work. However when I copied this file in `pre-commit` it works.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it doesn't work on an empty repository.
I just committed a file in my repository and when i excute `git checkout -b new_branch`, the post-checkout hook worked.

Comment: Good point. It should work also when you checkout a file.

Comment: Strange: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44427458/6309 show it should work. I just tested it by making a `myrepo/.git/hooks/post-checkout` file, and the checked out just one file (even though it wasn't even modified!): It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw a `post-checkout.sample` in `mingw64/share/git-core/templates/hooks/` of a [Git For Windows distribution](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

But that hook should work, provided you make it:

- a file named "post-checkout"
- a bash script (see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33643299/6309))
- in your `repo/.git/hooks` folder

There was actually a [proposal (RFC) for a `post-checkout.sample` in 2009](https://public-inbox.org/git/20091014201257.GA5788@book.hvoigt.net/), but it was not picked up at the time.

The question [was asked (also in 2009)](https://public-inbox.org/git/40aa078e0908171326g75cba2rc747c0d14a38cd0@mail.gmail.com/T/#u):

> > I also noticed that the
> > post-checkout sample does not exist when I init a new archive. Is this a
> > bug?
>
> No, it's security.
> Hooks are executable files and shouldn't blindly be
> copied around for security reasons.