# Automatically cleaning specific files between checkouts

Tags: git, git-checkout

Our project is on git, but our compilation product is not. Now, we need a way to automatically delete the compiled product (lets say `kuku.exe`) from the folder when we're checking out a new branch (because it became irelevant, and we want our scripts to tell us we have to compile again).

How do we do that? Something in git ignore or git attribute?

Comment: Just updated the question - We need git to automatically do it when we're checking out a different branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your binary is correctly ignored by Git (`.gitignore`), the checkout can proceed.

Upon successful completion, a [`post-checkout` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) can then delete/clean the working space, in order for any compilation to start from fresh.
See [here for a post-checkout installation example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892987/6309).