# Automatically Increase build number when creating a git branch

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-bash

Hi I wanted to know how can I automatically increase my iOS project build number when creating a new git branch. This is something that I have seen in a project that I have worked on but I couldn't see how its was implemented.

Should I have a script in the `.git/hooks` folder? Or there is another way?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You can try [`post-checkout` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35182000/7976758)

Comment: Thanks @phd I will try with that.