# Is there an add-on for Bitbucket Server that will allow you to add TO-DO comments prior to a branch being checked out?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish. Sometimes, due to time constraints, code has been written poorly. The code gets merged and may not be changed again for quite some time.

I would like to be able to add comments to a branch (let's call it Branch_A), so that the next time someone checks out the Branch_A or creates a branch off of it (let's call that Branch_A_1) that the developer would be able to see the list of things to be fixed.

Even if it's as simple as a bulleted list, that would be great.

Of course, you could just check in a .txt file to the branch with a list of things to do, but then the developer may never open that file.

Assuming you are writing Java, you could also leave //TODO comments in your code, but that ends up being a Sonar violation.

Comment: "*the developer would be able to see the list of things to be fixed*" If there is a Bitbucket plugin for this, how/where do you want it to be displayed? Have you considered a [git checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1011557/2745495)? Or how about on the opposite end, a git commit hook?

Comment: I will look into a checkout hook. As for where I want it displayed, I'm not really sure. I don't have a strong opinion about it. I was more concerned about if the base functionality existed.

Comment: @GinoMempin I discovered an app for Bitbucket that sort-of does what I'm asking for. https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222754/issues-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview. This has the advantage of being both a to-do list and it is visible to people other than developers. I'm not sure if this is what I'll end up using, but I thought I would reply and make sure others know about it. It's still pretty new, but it's free!  Thank you for responding to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered an app for Bitbucket that sort-of does what I'm asking for. marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222754/…. This has the advantage of being both a to-do list and it is visible to people other than developers.

Comment: Might as well use JIRA then: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira. I thought you were looking for something that displays info on git checkout. This isn't it, but it is one of the "popular" ways of tracking all the things a team needs to still work on,