# Git checkout command overrides folders in .gitignore

Tags: git, npm, gitignore

I'm working on this project under a tight schedule and I have this error, below is a summary of how I got this error.

- Working on `Weatherme` for viewing the weather location (my first actual implementation of APIs with Vue.js 3)
- Got tired of the old design and decided to move to `TailwindCSS` - my definition of a sweet library
- Made a new branch `migrate-design-tailwind` to push to GitHub
- I recently switch to the default branch (`main`) to get a copy of a piece of functionality.

The issue is when I check the `package.json` file in Visual Studio Code, it tells me certain packages are not available (not a problem right)

So I re-installed the packages and the errors go away. That was the first time. The second time the same dependencies weren't found. This is a sample of my `.gitignore`

```
# Node modules
/node_modules

# Project logs
/logs

# Other stuff, don't look here
todo.txt
tailwind.full.config.js
```

The checkout command I used is `git checkout main`

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/OyewoleOyedeji/weatherme.git)

Comment: `.gitignore` isn't used by `git checkout` at all. The purpose of the file is to prevent files from being added by `git add` and to tell `git status` to ignore them as untracked files. `git` also doesn't know or care about what `node` packages are installed; it simply keeps track of changes to the file `package.json` that *`node`* uses to manage the environment.

Comment: This means that I always have to install the packages after every checkout, right?

Comment: Yes, because the packages themselves are not part of the repository, only the file that tells `node` what packages to install.

Comment: @chepner happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a library called [husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/), which can be found on `npm` or `yarn` which helps in the process of adding git hooks to a project.

Installation is pretty simple for `npm` users - `$ npx husky-init && npm install`
Installation differs for `yarn` users

```sh
$ npx husky-init && yarn              # Yarn 1
$ yarn dlx husky-init --yarn2 && yarn # Yarn 2
```

I could get the checkout hook in my project easily using the command

`$ npx husky add .husky/post-checkout "npm install"`

I found all the hooks for git at [this site](https://githooks.com)

Happy New Year ✌

Answer (score 1):

After you check out your code you need to do `npm install`, more or less every time.  If you make sure your `package-lock.json` is checked in and restored when you check out your code, you'll install a reproducible set of packages.

Comment: Isn't there a way to store a version of the node_modules folder without committing changes to the HEAD

Comment: I mean for each branch. Thanks for the rapid response though 

Comment: So is there a way to automate this process

Comment: I don't think so, but you can try `pnpm` https://pnpm.io/ so you don't have to download everything every time. If you wanted I guess you could connect it to a checkout hook (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011557/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-a-hook-after-a-new-branch-has-been-checked-out-in-git)

Comment: Happy new year guys, Gavin Haynes could you give an answer with pnpm, I seem hooked